# I stopped downloading a movie on Mega, but I still have filled storage

Tags: windows, hard-drive

First of all, I'm not a computer expert and english isn't my native language, anyway, I was downloading a 12 GB movie on Mega, around 83% it told me, that i dont have any space left in c drive, so I made some space and then it stopped downlading and kept telling me, that i dont have any space left, so i gave up and stopped the downloading, but the storage on the c drive is still filled, i can't find it anywhere, btw it told me that i have full HMTL5 storage

Comment: Did you empty the Trash/Recycle?

Comment: Or maybe it was stored in the temp directory. Try Disk Cleanup.

Comment: I tried both, still nothing